# What Access-Control-* headers to send back in response to CORS preflight OPTIONS request and then subsequent GET/POST/etc. request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway

I'm setting up a custom authorization workflow on API Gateway and looking for insights on CORS.

I have an authorizer that returns an IAM role based on validation of a barertoken - that then invokes the lambda my target endpoint which returns the response as desired.

I've made this work by adding my barer token to both the `OPTIONS` method and the `GET`/`POST` methods.

In general, I'm adding most CORS headers to the `OPTIONS` + `GET`/`POST`/`etc` methods, but this seems superfluous.

I'm a little outside of my depth here, but intuitively - if I needed to add the exact same headers in my `OPTIONS` method and the target method I think AWS would simply aggregate the headers from the target methods into the preflight options config, so I assume I'm adding the headers unnecessarily somewhere, but I'm not sure.

Could someone please provide an overview / walk-through of how headers are being passed by API Gateway on a CORS api call?

example info:

```
endpoint: api.example.com/logout
methods: OPTIONS, GET
```

Currently I have:
`OPTIONS`/`GET`:

```
request headers:
 > barerToken
response headers: 
 > set-Cookie: integration.response.body.payload.httpCookie
 > Access-Control-Allow-Headers: 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,barerToken'
 > Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 'https://example.com'
 > Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: 'true'
 > set-cookie: integration.response.body.payload.cookie
 > Access-Control-Allow-Methods: 'OPTIONS,POST'
```

My intuition says I should only need the following:
`OPTIONS`:

```
request headers:
 > barerToken
response headers:
 > Access-Control-Allow-Headers: 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,barerToken'
 > Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 'https://example.com'
 > Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: 'true'
 > Access-Control-Allow-Methods: 'OPTIONS,POST'
```

`GET`:

```
response headers: 
 > set-Cookie: integration.response.body.payload.httpCookie
 > set-cookie: integration.response.body.payload.cookie
```

My understanding is that the flow is as follows:
`Browser (Preflight) -> End Point (OPTIONS) ->  Browser (Request) -> Authorizer Lambda -> End Point (GET) -> Browser (Response)`

OR

`Browser (Preflight) ->  Authorizer Lambda -> End Point (OPTIONS) ->  Browser (Request) -> End Point (GET) -> Browser (Response)`

But I could easily be mistaken.

Lastly, should I only apply the authorizer to the `OPTIONS` method or should it be applied to the `OPTIONS` and `GET` methods? What are the advantages/disadvantages of one versus both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm adding most CORS headers to the `OPTIONS` + `GET`/`POST`/`etc` methods, but this seems superfluous.

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header is never superfluous. It must be included in all responses, regardless of the HTTP method of the request.

The `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` headers are consulted by the browser only during the CORS preflight. For the specific spec section which states the relevant requirements, see https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-preflight-fetch. So you must include those in `OPTIONS` responses, but you can omit them from responses to other HTTP methods if you want.

The `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` response header can be omitted from responses to `OPTIONS` requests, but it must be included in responses to other methods.

> Could someone please provide an overview / walk-through of how headers are being passed by API Gateway on a CORS api call?

1. Your frontend code tells the browser it wants to send a request with a `barerToken` header.
2. Your browser says, OK, requests with a `barerToken` header require me to do a CORS preflight `OPTIONS` check to make sure the server allows requests with the `barerToken` header.
3. Your browser sends the server an `OPTIONS` request **with no cookies, and no `barerToken` header included** (because the `OPTIONS` check’s whole purpose is to see if it’s OK to include that header) and `Access-Control-Request-Headers` and `Access-Control-Request-Method` request headers (to tell the server what headers and method the server must give the OK for).
4. Your server sees the `OPTIONS` request and sends back a 200 OK response that includes the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response headers (to indicate what headers and methods it’s giving the OK for), and with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header (to indicate if it is OK with requests from the origin the request came from).
5. Your browser evaluates the preflight `OPTIONS` response to determine whether it succeeds — based on the specific values in the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, and the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response headers.
6. If the preflight succeeds, the browser moves on to make the actual `GET`/`POST`/whatever request from your frontend JavaScript code — **with cookies and the `barerToken` header included**.
7. Your server sees the request, uses the cookies and `barerToken` value to do any authentication required — and then sends back whatever response you have configured, including the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` (again) and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` response headers.