# CORS custom header stripped from request

Tags: cors, aws-api-gateway, fetch-api, preflight, lambda-authorizer

I'm using a token based lambda authorizer as described here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html

Right now I'm still using the toy example where the header prop is `tokenHeader`

My fetch is as follows:

```
export function logout() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
      return fetch('https://account-api.example.com/v1/logout', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Request-Method': 'GET',
          'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'tokenHeader':'allow',
        },
        credentials: 'include'
      })
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json().then((body) => {
            return {
              status: body.statusCode,
              payload:body.payload,
            };
          },
          );
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("response", response)
          if (response.status !== 200) {
            dispatch({ type: 'LOGOUT_ERROR', payload: response.payload.error});
          }
          if (response.status === 200) {
            dispatch({ type: 'LOGOUT_SUCCESSFUL', payload: response.payload });
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          dispatch({ type: 'LOGOUT_FAILED', payload: String(error)});
        })
    };
  }
```

When I look at the network tab the `'tokenHeader':'allow'` header is missing from my request, resulting in a 401 from the authorizer - what do I need to do to prevent this header from being stripped?

[image: request is missing tokenHeader header]

Side Note: **This request works in postman**

API Gateway Configurations (Not sure if this is relevant):

OPTIONS
  Request
[image: OPTIONS Method Request]
  Response
[image: OPTIONS Integration Response]

GET
  Request
[image: GET Method Request]
  Response
[image: GET Integration Response]

I don't want to ignore CORS and am sending data between `account-api.example.com` and `dev.example.com` so please no answers indicating to remove/ignore cors -- my goal is to properly implement cors.

Comment: May I know how you deploy API Gateway

Comment: @pubudut sure, what are you looking at specifically? I'm using the AWS UI not CLI or serverless, what can I share that would help in debugging this? Thanks, -E

Comment: did you try this approach https://serverless.com/blog/cors-api-gateway-survival-guide/ this is basically serverless approach.Postman does not do preflight check so it works there but browsers does.I was able use this approach to work with cors.

Comment: if you use console then you could add headers to your API gateway response headers to allow cors

Comment: @pubudut yes, I used aspects of that guide - my endpoint works, and my browser is able to access it - the issue is my header `tokenheader` is stripped from the request header. If I change my authorizer to default to 'allow' it works fine - this indicates (I think) that it isn't expressly a cors issue, but something with the fetch-api stripping my custom header from the request

Comment: @sideshowbarker -- thank you, I was confused about the order things were happening (I'd love it if you laid out a response simply here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58807058/api-gateway-cors-auth)

Also -- if you post this comment as an answer I'll accept it -- (for future viewers) the correct answer is there shouldn't be authentication on the OPTIONS method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details in the question show that the custom header isn’t being sent in the CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request. That’s expected — any custom headers you set in your frontend code won’t be included in the CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request. There’s no way you can prevent that behavior.

So the bottom line is: if you use an authentication mechanism that relies on a particular header being added to requests, you need to configure the server to not require that custom header for `OPTIONS` requests — because the CORS protocol requires servers to allow `OPTIONS` requests without any authentication.

In more detail, what’s happening is this:

1. Your code’s telling your browser it wants to send a request with a custom `tokenHeader` header.
2. Your browser says, OK, requests with a `tokenHeader` header require me to do a CORS preflight `OPTIONS` to make sure the server allows requests with the `tokenHeader` header.
3. Your browser sends the `OPTIONS` request to the server **without the `tokenHeader` header**, because the whole purpose of the `OPTIONS` check is to see if it’s OK to include that header.
4. Your server sees the `OPTIONS` request but instead of responding to it in a way that indicates it allows the `tokenHeader` header in requests, it rejects it with a 401 since it lacks the header.
5. Your browser expects a 200 or 204 response for the CORS preflight but instead gets that 401 response. So your browser stops right there and never tries the `GET` request from your code.

Answer (score -1):

You might need to do follow this approach for AWS Console

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Comment: I believe I've done all of that stuff -- I updated my question with the API Gateway settings.

I'm not sure why, regardless of my API Gateway settings, the browser isn't showing the custom header in the network -- that's the part that has me thinking it's an issue with the fetch-api

Comment: what about this https://medium.com/@slmkitani/passing-custom-headers-through-amazon-api-gateway-to-an-aws-lambda-function-f3a1cfdc0e29

Comment: I just stepped away from my computer - I'll give it a shot and let you know! I'm not sure where the authorizer falls in the stack